# Show popup when hovering a table cell

Tags: html, css, angular

[image: I want to display the details on hover on the <code><td></code> element on HTML just like shown . How do I achieve that]

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of collection.data | paginate: config">
        <th scope="row">
          <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" [attr.id]="item.id">
            <label class="custom-control-label" [attr.for]="item.id"></label>
          </div>
        </th>
        <td>{{item.name}}
          ----code here----
          </span>
        </td>
```

I have the HTML code above written and on hover on the name I should be able to view the details.

Comment: Something stopping you from making this happen? Is there a problem?

Comment: yes, actually what is happening is I am putting the code in span and the table is expanding and also I have the position as relative. I am not sure why is this happening

Comment: Table is expanding because you didn't take the hidden element out of the document flow. If it appears the cell grows and then the table expands. You need to set its position to absolute to take it out of the document flow.

Answer (score 6):

Give the table cell a position of `relative`, then you give the popup a position of `absolute` so that's its overlapping. Then just toggle its display on hover. I control the offset with `translateY`.

```css
.has-details {
  position: relative;
}

.details {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateY(70%) scale(0);
  transition: transform 0.1s ease-in;
  transform-origin: left;
  display: inline;
  background: white;
  z-index: 20;
  min-width: 100%;
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.has-details:hover span {
  transform: translateY(70%) scale(1);
}

td {
  padding: 1rem;
  background: whitesmoke;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class='has-details'>
      hover for details
      <span class="details">more info here</span>
    </td>
    <td>stuff</td>
    <td>stuff</td>
    <td>stuff</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='has-details'>
      hover for details
      <span class="details">more info here</span>
    </td>
    <td>stuff</td>
    <td>stuff</td>
    <td>stuff</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='has-details'>
      hover for details
      <span class="details">more info here</span>
    </td>
    <td>stuff</td>
    <td>stuff</td>
    <td>stuff</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```